# Copying a single file into a zip archive

Tags: excel, vba, zip

it's my first time here.
I've looked into it for hours and can't find an answer.

I need to copy a single file from a folder into a zip archive (not all the files in the folder like everyone does).
The code works fine for copying all files in a folder but when I put a single filename instead it creates the zip file put does not put anything in it.

```
Private Sub Archive(sClientWB As String)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim sArchiveDir As String
    sArchiveDir = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + cClientFolder + "Archive\"
    'Create folder if does not exist
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sArchiveDir) Then fso.CreateFolder (sArchiveDir)

    Dim vFileNameZip
    vFileNameZip = sArchiveDir + fso.GetBaseName(sClientWB) + ".zip"

    'create the empty zipfile
    Open vFileNameZip For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1

    Dim objApp As Object
    Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    'add file to zip archive
    objApp.Namespace(vFileNameZip).CopyHere sClientWB
    'nothing happens, the file is not added to the zip

    'when I execute this instead :
    objApp.Namespace(vFileNameZip).CopyHere objApp.Namespace(ActiveWorkbook.Path + cClientFolder).items
    'works fine, all the files in the folder get copied in the zip file

End Sub
```

I have explicitly verify the sClientWB parameter and it is valid.
Folder strusture is
\Gestion Clients\Liste Clients.xlsm
\Gestion Clients\Clients\LapFre20180908.xlsm
\Gestion Clients\Clients\Archive\LapFre20180908.zip
Current workbook is \Gestion Clients\Liste Clients.xlsm

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Make sure you're using Variants not Strings for any parameters you pass to objApp.  I notice `sClientWB` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim Williams mentioned in his comment, change `sClientWB` to be a `Variant` instead of a string.

You'll also want a brief pause after the `.CopyHere` statement to allow it time to actually process. Here's the code I use:

This gets the count of the number of files currently in the zip archive

```
Dim ShellApp As Object
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Dim CurrentFileCount As Long
CurrentFileCount = ShellApp.NameSpace(Archive.ArchivePath & Archive.ArchiveName).Items.Count
```

This actually copies the file to the archive

```
ShellApp.NameSpace(Archive.ArchivePath & Archive.ArchiveName).CopyHere Archive.filePath & Archive.fileName
```

This loop waits until the file count has increased which tells me that it's done compressing.

```
Do Until ShellApp.NameSpace(Archive.ArchivePath & Archive.ArchiveName).Items.Count > CurrentFileCount

  Dim Pause As Date

  Pause = DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
  While Now < Pause
    DoEvents
  Wend
Loop
```

Note that I have created a class `Archive` that holds all the various and sundry bits necessary to create an archive file and populate it. Here are the referenced bits from above:

```
Const ARCHIVE_PATH As String = "Archive\"
Private pArchiveName As Variant                   'name of the zip file
Private pArchivePath As Variant                   'path to the zip file
Public Property Get ArchiveName() As Variant
  ArchiveName = pArchiveName
End Property
Public Property Let ArchiveName(ByVal Value As Variant)
  pArchiveName = Value
End Property
Public Property Get ArchivePath() As Variant
  ArchivePath = pArchivePath
End Property
Public Property Let ArchivePath(ByVal Value As Variant)
  pArchivePath = Value & ARCHIVE_PATH
End Property
```

The `Const ARCHIVE_PATH` is because I always put my archives in a directory below where the "raw" data lives. You can adjust this as necessary.

Comment: I changed the sub parameter to : vClientWB as variant  
but I still get the same behavior, the file is not copied.  
For the waiting time, I just removed it for now for it hang forever since the file is never created.  
Is it because I pass a string variable to the parameter when I call the sub?

Comment: The problem is that it _won't_ wait forever. Your code will move on _without_ waiting for the file to compress and be added to the ZIP file, the `Sub` will end, your variable `fso` will go out of scope and be destroyed, and all processing of the zip will terminate. If you _don't_ wait you'll _never_ get your file added. If the file is <1k in size, it _might_ get added quickly enough that you don't actually have to pause, but in most cases, it'll take time. Try zipping it from Win Explorer and see how long it takes!

Comment: I'm testing with a barely empty workbook, it zips instantly. I don't think this is an issue since the alternative (to zip everything in the folder, ie 4 files) works well without waiting.

Comment: Not sure where to go from here. The code I posted works for me - it's in a small `Sub` that I call repeatedly to add 1 file at a time to my ZIP. Looking at the [`.CopyHere` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder-copyhere), there's a flag to tell it to not prompt to overwrite the file if it already exists. Is it possible that the file exists in your ZIP to begin with? _/Clutching at straws..._

Comment: @FrédéricLaprise - this [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder) lists all the methods & properties of the `Folder` object. You may want to break your code just before the `.CopyHere` call and look through them all to see if you can identify anything weird that may be causing your issue.

Comment: in the line "ShellApp.NameSpace(Archive.ArchivePath & Archive.ArchiveName).CopyHere Archive.filePath & Archive.fileName", how exactly do you declare Archive.filePath and Archive.fileName? I will try to replicate exaclty your code to try and understand whats going on.

Comment: @FrédéricLaprise - see updates. You should be able to declare them as local variables of type `Variant` and get the same effect.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! Looking at your code, I've finally found the problem. When I called the "Archive" sub, I was passing a variable declared as a string to the variant "vClientWB" parameter, this what was causing the issue. I changed the variable in the calling procedure to a variant also and now everything works fine.

Comment: @FrédéricLaprise - glad you were able to get it worked out!